# How to automate a source command

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, login, source

I have to run a command every morning after I log on to the server to enable certain company specific functionalities.

The command looks like this:
source /data/dev/int/default/somethingsomething.env

Is there a way to automate this so I don't have to copy/paste it?

Comment: What shell do you use?

Comment: zsh apparently, had no idea how to even check this till now

Comment: @Wildcard, I didn't see a zsh answer in there, so I went ahead and posted an Answer here.

Comment: The "duplicate" was about sourcing a tcsh script when opening a terminal (that starts a bash shell on CentOS), quite different here. The answers there certainly don't apply here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Files, I would recommend placing the command in your ~/.zshrc file.

> Then, if the shell is interactive, commands are read from /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc

Where [ZDOTDIR](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell) can be set to override the default value of `$HOME`.